# SHOW TABLES that contain an element in a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySQL database with a few tables that each contain a `username` column with that user's relevant data.

I have been using `SHOW TABLES` to offer a dropdown select menu to the user, but realised I only want to show those relevant to the current user (so tables where at least one row has `User1` in the `username` column).

I have been looking into `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` but am not sure if it actually gets me any closer.

Is this even possible in one query, without restructuring the database?

Comment: Perform SELECT to INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS and select all tablenames into temptable. Then query each table iteratively for the needed value presence (use prepared statement), delete the tablename when not found. Then use this temptable rowset as a datasource of your dropdown list.

Comment: You can write code that writes SQL. Query the schema for all tables with that column name, then combines all of those table names in to a new query.

Answer (score 1):

First you must define a cursor so that you cyclically have access to all tables that contain the column "username";

```
DECLARE curtables 
    CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS isc WHERE isc.COLUMN_NAME = 'username' (...)
```

Then, inside the cursor, check if the table "TABLE_NAME" has the value "user1", through COUNT.

```
SELECT COUNT(username) FROM "TABLE_NAME" WHERE username = 'user1'
```

If the result is greater than zero, then you add table "TABLE_NAME" to a semicolon-separated string.

At the end, put the values ​​of the string separated by semicolon in a table and then that table in a dropdown select menu.

Guess you should reach what you want with this.